# Nodelist on convert to an Array list give empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

Im trying to convert a NodeList from javascript to a array but i got a empty array on the convert, im doing something like this:

```
var children = this.container.childNodes;
console.log(children); //show all the children type NodeList
console.log(Array.from(children)); //show empty array
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(children)); //show empty array too
```

Comment: Some websites override the built-in functions. Make sure, yours doesn’t. `Array.from(someNodeList)` works; show us a [mcve].

Comment: My guess is this a *logging* issue. Your element is empty when you run this code but gets populated at some point after you run this code. I can reproduce this in Chrome by (1) closing my console, (2) running your code against an empty element, and then (3) adding children to the element before I (4) open the console again. (Test code: https://jsfiddle.net/bc8yfxwa/) In that case, the NodeList reflects the (populated) state of the element at the time I opened the console, while the arrays reflect its original empty state at the time I ran the code. (cc @SebastianSimon)

Comment: @apsillers you are right.